# Trying to set up Angular 2 input validation that requires specific patterns

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular2-forms

I'm trying to set up input validation in Angular 2. I'm unsure how to create a regular expression pattern to the validators.pattern

Pattern should look like any of these: 1M01, 12M12, 2M04, 2M04a, 2M04b, 2M04aa, 2M04ba.

For example 1M01 as `pattern`

```
pattern: any = '[0-9]{1}[M]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}'
cuenumber: any = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, 
                                Validators.pattern(this.pattern)
                                ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You did it right, it does not work ?
Try this :

```
const myPattern: string = '[0-9]{1}[M]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}';
this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
    'name': new FormControl('', [
        Validators.pattern(myPattern)
    ])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
 <input class="form-control"  #EmpCode="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="EmpCode" name="EmpCode"
  type="text" value="" pattern="EmpCodePattern">

EmpCodePattern: any = '[0-9]{1}[M]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}'
```